# Class to minimize all forms

Tags: c#, winforms, class

How I will Convert this into class which minimize all the childform? When I try to transfer it into class I got error :

> *The type or namespace name 'MdiChildren' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

```
public void minimizeAll()
{
   foreach (Form childForm in MdiChildren)
   {
      childForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MdiChildren` is not a static property, you need to use an instance of a form. You could pass in a Form as a parameter.

```
public void minimizeAll(Form parentForm)
{
   foreach (Form childForm in parentForm.MdiChildren)
   {
      childForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you have moved the code to new class, the implicit `this.` reference from the `MDIChildren` property which previously was linked to your `Windows` `Form` object is no longer available and you need to pass and accept the `Form` object in your new class as below:

```
public class NewClass
{
    public void minimizeAll(System.Windows.Forms.Form yourForm)
    {
        if(yourForm == null) throw new InvalidArgumentException();

        foreach (Form childForm in yourForm.MdiChildren)
        {
           childForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try using something like this (hardly you have *many* MDI parent forms):

```
public static class Minimizer {
  public static void MinimizeMdiChildren() {
    // Enumerate all forms, minimize MDI Children
    foreach (Form form in Application.OpenForms) 
      if (form.IsMdiChild)
        form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
  }
}
...
Minimizer.MinimizeMdiChildren();
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is add `using MdiChildren;` at the top by the other using directives, and add the `MdiChildren` namespace as a reference.

To add a reference in Visual Studio you right click the project name, on the project explorer to the right of the application, and scroll down the popup-menu until you reach Add reference.  From here you select the namespace you want referenced in your project, and click ok.

from here in the `ForEach` just type in the class path where you had `MdiChildren` previously.  Something like `MdiChildren.TheClass`

Comment: This won't help. `MdiChildren` is not a namespace, it's [a property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.mdichildren.aspx).

Comment: I thought `MDiChildren` was a class?

Comment: It's a property that the class `Form` has. If it was a class, it wouldn't be possible to do `foreach(Form childForm in MdiChildren)`. You're right in looking into the `using` statements in regards to the error OP posted though. Often that's the cause but not in this case :)

Comment: I had thought MdiChildren resided in a class library, and the OP needed to access the properties in the MdiChildren class.